# How many more test cases are required to achieve provide 100% statement and 100% decision coverage?

Tags: manual-testing, interview, coverage, istqb, test-coverage

You have designed test cases to provide 100% statement and 100% decision coverage for the following fragment of code.

```
if width > length
then
biggest_dimension = width
else
biggest_dimension = length
end_if
```

The following has been added to the bottom of the code fragment above.

```
print “Biggest dimension is ” & biggest_dimension
print “Width: ” & width
print “Length: ” & length
```

**How many more test cases are required?**

The options are :

**A.** One more test case will be required for 100 % decision coverage.
**B.** Two more test cases will be required for 100 % statement coverage, one of which will be used to provide 100% decision coverage.
**C.** None, existing test cases can be used.
**D.** One more test case will be required for 100″ statement coverage.

**But according to me D should be correct but the correct answer is C . How is it possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Considering the given piece of code following cases can given 100% Decision and 100% Statement Coverage.

Case 1

```
Width = 10
Length = 5
```

Case 2

```
Width = 5
Length = 10
```

Now, you add the three statements to print the result. These will also be covered with the above mentioned cases.

[image]

Since there is no new decision added to the script, it would be obvious that new cases wouldn't be required for 100% Decision Coverage.

The 3 print statements added to the script will execute regardless of whether the decision is false or true. Hence the same 2 cases mentioned above will provide 100% statement Coverage. You don't need to add new cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) now it is clear

Comment: can you please tell the tool which you are using for flowcharts design?

Comment: Im using Draw.io for flowcharts as well as other diagrams.